# Loading images into big size imageviews

Tags: android

I know that ,according to android docs, that if you have a big image. Then you scale it down to size of the image view you are loading it to (using the decodeResources and Options class).

Now my question is, lets say you want to load background picture and the source image is of similar size, do you just load the image? Or do you actually scale it down a bit and then using the FITXY to stretch it?

I am trying to avoid Out Of Memory exceptions here
Thank you

Comment: If it's only 1 image on whole, even high definition screen - it shouldn't be an issue. You will not have an OOM.

Comment: Well because  will be adding more images to the screen  (a lot!) so I want to conserve as much as I can

Comment: You should put more dots on screen then screen can show itself. So e.h. 2560x something is currently maxim which is not too big.